# Twig separation if statement

Tags: symfony, twig

I have in template 10-20 same if statements.

Example:

```
{% if a == b %}
    <div>text</div>
{% endif %}

other code

{% if a == b %}
    <span></span>
{% endif %}

other code

{% if a == b %}
    <div>text 2</div>
{% endif %}
```

and now if I need change condition I must change it in several places.

How can I easy separate this condition and change only in one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the conditions result in a variable:

```
{% set ab_cond = a == b %}

{% if ab_cond %}
    <div>text</div>
{% endif %}

other code

{% if ab_cond %}
    <span></span>
{% endif %}

other code

{% if ab_cond %}
    <div>text 2</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Calculate it once, store the result as a variable, use the variable in the if statements.

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining how to do this.